Adding new column on Alert Elasticsearch
I am currently working on a project Fraud Management to create rules that trigger alerts in Elasticsearch.
After receiving an alert, I want to know if it's possible to add a new column of data that can be inputted through the UI via the alert menu. However, our goal is to add a new column for each alert to include remarks or comments on each hit (transaction). Currently, my project only adds new columns using rule-based methods. so when it hit (transaction) trigger rule, it give new column value. Example :
Rule 1 : it gives the transaction "Risk":"Easy"
Rule 2 : it gives the transaction "Risk":"Medium"
etc
Could you please guide me on how to achieve this?
Thank you!
